# Problem in List of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, tuples

I have a list of tuples which i need to return a `[Int]` which are all the locations are dividable by 2 ..

```
type A = [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]

func :: A -> [Int]
func tuples =  [a | (a, b, c, d) <- tuples, map a `mod` 2 == 0]
```

---

```
func [(244,244,244,244),(244,244,244,244),(244,244,244,244)]
```

**Output**

```
[244,244,244]
```

I have the current code but problem is this only checking position of a .. but i required to all *a ,b , c,d*  ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type A = (Int, Int, Int, Int)
func :: [A] -> [Int]
func t =  [a | (a, b, c, d) <- t, all even [a,b,c,d]]
```

The `all` function returns true only if everything given satisfies the predicate.  I've bundled the tuple into a list and checked the predicate.

Comment: ``all (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0) [a,b,c,d]`` can be simplified to `all even [a,b,c,d]`.

Comment: also its not a :) `(a, b, c, d)` in the generator

Answer (score 2):

Just add some more guards for `b`, `c` and `d`:

```
a `divides` b =  b `mod` a == 0
func tuples =  [a | (a, b, c, d) <- tuples, all (divides 2) [a,b,c,d]]
```

Comment: thanks this method also works but jeffs answer looks clean :-)

Comment: also its not a :) (a, b, c, d) in the generator

Comment: @Sudantha I forgot about the function `even` when I wrote this code. It's definitly cleaner.